# Какими способами улучшить решение через BST?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, структуры-данных, graph

Я решил задачу по подсчету элементов на конкретном уровне(расстоянии) от корня графа. Вполне понимаю что мое решение можно и нужно улучшить. Не могли бы вы посоветовать какие конкретные вещи стоит оптимизировать в моем коде?

```
using namespace std;

int num = 0;
vector<int> graph[100000];

int countLevel(const int lvl, const int root) {
    queue<int> q;
    int level[100000] = {0};
    bool visited[100000] = {0};
  int cnt = 0;
    q.push(root);
    level[root] = 1;
    visited[root] = 1;
    while (q.size() != 0) {
        int current = q.front();
        q.pop();
        if (level[current] == lvl) 
      cnt++;
        if (level[current] > lvl) 
      break;
        for (int i = 0; i < graph[current].size(); i++) {
            if (!visited[graph[current][i]]) {
                q.push(graph[current][i]);
                level[graph[current][i]] = level[current] + 1;
                visited[graph[current][i]] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}

int main() {
    cin >> num;
    for(int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        graph[a].push_back(b);
        graph[b].push_back(a);
    }
    int level;
    cin >> level;
    cout << countLevel(level, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну здесь реализован поиск в ширину (BFS, а не BST), принципиально быстрее ничего нет.

Вот только зачем продолжать работу, если достигнут уровень `lvl`?

Сразу после `cnt++;` нужно переходить к следующей итерации цикла, не вызывая  `for` для данного узла.

```
 if (level[current] == lvl) 
      cnt++;
 else
      for...
```

Comment: Да, ошибся в названии. Действительно добавлять узлы на большем расстоянии уже не имеет смысла. Спасибо большое )